# xaml datagrid issue when binding to linq join

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, linq

In my WPF desktop application I try to retrieve data from a linq join in a datagrid using entity framework.

These are the objects:

```
[Table("parParameters")]
public partial class ParametersEntity
{
    [Key]
    public int parUid { get; set; }

    [StringLength(5)]
    public string parGroup { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string parCode { get; set; }

    [StringLength(100)]
    public string parDescription { get; set; }

    public bool parEnabled { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime parModifyDate { get; set; }
}

[Table("cliClient")]
public partial class ClientEntity
{
    [Key]
    public int cliUid { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int cliParUid { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(10)]
    public string cliType { get; set; }
}
```

I have the following query:

```
CollectionViewSource viewSource = ((CollectionViewSource)(this.FindResource("viewSource")));
context.cliClient.Join(
    context.parParameters,
    cli => cli.cliParUid,
    par => par.parUid,
    (cli, par) => new { Cli = cli, Par = par })                                                  
    .ToList();
viewSource.Source = context.cliClient.Local;
```

And here is the XAML code:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="cliClientGrid" SelectionMode="Single" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="false" IsEnabled="True" IsReadOnly="True" EnableRowVirtualization="True" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected" Margin="5,5,5,5" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource viewSource}}">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="cliParUidColumn" Binding="{Binding Path=cliParUid}" Header="Language:" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="cliTypeColumn" Binding="{Binding Path=cliType}" Header="Client Type:" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

It ends up with the following results:
“Language” column is listing correct descriptions, whereas the “Language” column retrieve the cliParUid.

Once I replace the XAML string `Binding="{Binding Path=cliParUid}"` with `{Binding Path=parParameters.parDescription}"` is the “Language” column remaining blank. How can I display the corresponding language description in there?

Comment: What is `parParameters` that you are trying to bind to? The `ClientEntity` class should have a navigation property.

Comment: Your assistance is highly appreciated @mm8
`parParameters.parDescription` is basically the corresponding language description to the `cliClient.cliParUid`
Once I set the navigation property `public virtual ParametersEntity ParametersEntity { get; set; }` to the `ClientEntity` get I stuck with below exception message:
System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException: 'An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details.'

inner exception
SqlException: Invalid column name 'ParametersEntity_parUid'.

Comment: Thanks a lot @mm8 your navigation property hint resolved my problem. I have add the `[ForeignKey("cliParUid")]` syntax to the navigation property and now is the language description displayed as expected.